# What could cause my route to return error 500?

Tags: php, api, .htaccess, routes

I have an `index.php` file that looks like this :

```
print('Url = ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
return;
```

When I do :

```
$> curl http://localhost:8888/notapi/test
Url = /notapi/test
```

However, when I do :

```
$> curl http://localhost:8888/api/test   
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 you@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

I get an error 500, just by setting the url from `notapi` (or anything) to `api`.

**What could cause this error ?** I guess there is something in a file somewhere that says that `/api` is a special url that redirects somewhere else, but, as a beginner in PHP APIs, I have no idea where this could come from.

Here is my `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

**EDIT:**

Nothing shows off in my `/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log`.
I `tail` it in background so I can get updates when an error is displayed (with `tail -f /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log &`), but nothing is showed when I do my `curl` calls.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: @aynber yes, but nothing is showed in the logs. I edited my question

Comment: Add these at begining of index.php: `ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. It could be helpful for debuging.

Comment: "I guess there is something in a file somewhere" - But what other files do you have? Your setup looks very minimal. And this is a local test server that you presumably have complete control over? There shouldn't be anything in a default Apache install that should trigger such behaviour. Have you installed any additional security modules like mod_security perhaps?

Comment: "Nothing shows off in my /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log" - you need to look in the webserver/Apache error log (not the PHP error log) for details of the 500 error. PHP won't ordinarily trigger a 500 error, unless a fatal error occurs, display errors is Off and no other output is sent in the response.

Comment: please try removing `RewriteBase /` & let us know if issue still exists

Comment: Is `/api` a physical subdirectory?

Comment: @MrWhite `/Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error.log` does not show any error, and no, I do not have `/api` subdirectory.
@OmarTammam it seems to have no effect...

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I looked in my `.zsh_history` to see which files I edited.

It was not `php.ini` as I thought, but it was `httpd.conf`.

I had add these lines :

```
# Custom reverse proxy

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:8888/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /api/
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain / localhost:8888
<Location "/api/">
   ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
```

I commented out every line that contains `/api/`, like this:

```
# Custom reverse proxy

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost on
# ProxyPass /api/ http://localhost:8888/
# ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /api/
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain / localhost:8888
# <Location "/api/">
#    ProxyPassReverse /
# </Location>
```

I restarted MAMP, and now my `curl` calls do work.

(However, I added this in order to be linked with a flutter app, that do not work anymore now. But this is another issue.)